# Misfire still happening after a lot of diagnostic - Mechanic stumped

Tags: misfire, chrysler, town-and-country

I have a 2014 Town and Country that has been at garage for 5 weeks now.
It has a misfire issue on cylinder#2 at low idle (under 800RPM)
Mechanic is stumped by this issue, as he states mechanically there is nothing wrong with this cylinder.

- Sparkplug ok
- Coil ok
- Injector ok
- wire from injector to ECU ok
- replaced ECU with chrysler OEM ECU.  This helped with misfire but did not completely resolve it.
- He says valves and rocker arms are fine.
- fuel spray from injector ok
- wet and dry compression test ok
- No signs of a head gasket leak

I have been using this guy for 20years and trust him.  He is at a loss what can be causing this misfire on cylinder#2

Any one run into this type of issue and did you ever get resolution

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Could it have got a bad batch of fuel?

Comment: Can you feel the misfire, or is it the ecu telling you there is a misfire?

Comment: How long has it been doing this?